# VBA Kill function not deleting file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written VBA code for Microsoft Word to send an email when a button is clicked. When the button is clicked, and the macro is completed, I would like the file to be deleted from the Desktop.

When I run this macro now, Microsoft Word closes out, but the file is not deleted from my desktop.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document
Dim FileName        As String
Dim FilePath        As String
Dim DeletePath      As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
myFileName = "Form"
FilePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\desktop\"
Doc.SaveAs2 FileName:=FilePath & myFileName & ".docx", Fileformat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
With EmailItem
    .Subject = "Bid Award Form"
    .Body = "Please Review the attached Bid Award form"
    .To = "EMAILADDRESS@DOMAIN.COM"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal 'Or olImprotanceHigh Or olImprotanceLow
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Send
End With

    'display a message using named arguments
MsgBox _
prompt:="Your email has been sent. Please check your Outlook sent mail for confirmation", _
Buttons:=vbOKOnly, _
Title:="Email Confirmation"



'Close the File
Doc.Close

Kill "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\desktop\form.docx"

'Close the Application of the document we are going to delete
Application.Quit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing



End Sub
```

Any help that you can provide will be very helpful!

Comment: you cannot delete a file that is open in an application

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking at the wrong file. `Kill` is a function, that makes no mistakes. 
Simply try the following:

```
Sub KillTheFile
    Kill "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\desktop\form.docx"
End Sub
```

Then see if it works. Probably you are having a file `frm.docx` or similar.

Comment: We have tried this sub by itself, and it works with the path provided. It is just in the context of the rest of the code that things get messed up.

Comment: @noldak - then put a stop before the `Kill`, and write `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. Then press F5 again. You might get lucky. Just for the record - by any chance, do you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I think you can just paste that into Immediate window (entire "kill ..." line only), press Enter and see if the file disappears. If not, try putting the full path and see if it works. That should give you some clues.

Comment: @LoganReed - pasting it in the immediate window is the same as the code, yup.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this instead

```
On Error Goto 0
Dim sDocName as string
sDocName = Doc.FullName
Doc.Close
Kill sDocName
```